# LINQ with ManyToMany: Filtering based on multiple selection

Tags: c#, linq, filter, many-to-many

I am a newbe to C# and have to use it for my master thesis. At the moment, I am facing a problem that is a bit to complex for me.

I have set up a database with a many-to-many relationship like this:

```
Table Relay:  
- id (PK)  
- Name  
- Input  

Table ProtectionFunction:  
- id (PK)  
- ANSI  
- IEC  
- Description  

Table RelayConfig (junction table)  
- RelayID (PK)  
- ProtFuncID (PK)  
- TimeToSaturate  
- Remanence
```

The thing is, a `Relay` can have multiple protection functions, and for each it has specific values for `TimeToSaturate` and `Remanence`. Now I want to realize a filter. The user can select protection function via checkboxes in a `DataGridView` and a `ListBox` should show all `Relay`s that support ALL of these protection functions.

I have already created the LINQ-to-SQL classes for my project. But now I am stuck because I don't know how to realize the filtering. All LINQ commands I have found so far would give me all `Relay`s for one protection function.

I really hope one of you can give me a hint.

Comment: Each `Relay` object should have a `RelayConfig(s)` property which should further have a `ProtectionFunction(s)` property which would only contain the ProtectionFunction's related to the current `Relay` instance. Is that not what you are seeing in your generated object model?

Comment: @M.Babcock - A 'RelayConfig' object will have a property 'ProtectionFunction' containing the single row that 'RelayConfig' is joined to. It will not be a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ids = new int[]{ ... }; 
// if ids is null or ids.Length == 0 please return null or an empty list, 
//do not go further otherwise you'll get Relays without any function filter

var query = Relays.AsQueryable(); 
foreach (var id in ids)    
{
     var tempId = id;
     query = query.Where(r=>r.RelayConfigs.Any(rc=>rc.ProtFuncID == tempId)); 
}
var items  = query.ToList();
```

**Update**
Just saw this on [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) page:

> The temporary variable in the loop is required to avoid the outer
>   variable trap, where the same variable is captured for each iteration
>   of the foreach loop.

Comment: Same problem here, look at my comment at the answer from jeroenh

Comment: I am sorry, I have tested this again and it seems that it selects all relays that support the protection function corresponding to the LAST id from ids. So if I use an array of ids that should give me no suitable relay, it gives me the ones mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you start from the RelayConfigs. Something like this should work:

```
 var protFuncIds = new[]{1,2,3};
 var query = from rc in db.RelayConfigs
             where protFuncIds.Contains(rc.ProtFuncID)
             select rc.Relay;
 var relays = query.Distinct().ToList();
```

UPDATE:
based on your comment, the following should work, however do monitor the SQL generated...

```
IQueryable<Relay> query = db.Relays

foreach (var id in ids)
   query = relays.Where(r => r.RelayConfigs.Select(x => x.ProtFuncId).Contains(id));

var relays = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Well, I think here is the problem that every relay is selected that has the protection function 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR any combination of it. What I am looking for is only the relays that support protection function 1 AND 2 AND 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Build a list of protection function ids from your checkbox list
var protFuncIDs = [1,2,3,4];

using(var dc = new MyDataContext())
{
    var result = dc.Relays.Where(r=>protFuncIDs.Join(r.RelayConfigs, pf=>pf, rc=>rc.ProtFuncID, (pf,rc)=>pf).Count() == protFuncIDs.Length).ToArray();
}
```

It's not especially efficient, but that should do the trick for you.

Comment: Wow that was really fast! Thank you. But unfortunatly I am getting an error. I had to change var protFuncIDs = [1,2,3,4]; to int[] protFuncIDs = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; at first because there was an error. Now when I run the code, I get an NotSupportedExeption from the LINQ command. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in Lightswitch, and here was my preprocess query:

```
partial void UnusedContactTypesByContact_PreprocessQuery(int? ContactID, ref IQueryable<ContactType> query)
    {
        query = from contactType in query
                where !contactType.ContactToContactTypes.Any(c => c.Contact.Id == ContactID)
                select contactType;
    }
```

Hope that helps.